# Using MYSQL are keys required on individual fields if in a unique key?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a simple linking table, see the create sql below.
My question is, do i need to have the individual indexes for amtw_propnameid_idx, and amt_amt_concept_id_idx if i have amtw_u1?
I use this table to join and filter on both amtw_propnameid and amtw_amt_concept_id.  I use the unique index to enforce the restriction that no two rows can be identical.

```
    $sql= "CREATE TABLE `refset_amt_webster` (
    amtw_id int unsigned not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    amtw_propnameid int null default null comment 'links to the Webster proprameid drugs table',
    amtw_amt_concept_id bigint not null comment 'links to the AMT concept id',
    amtw_disabled tinyint unsigned not null default 0 comment '1=disabled',
    PRIMARY KEY(amtw_id),
    KEY amtw_propnameid_idx (amtw_propnameid),
    KEY amtw_amt_concept_id_idx (amtw_amt_concept_id),
    UNIQUE KEY amtw_u1 (amtw_propnameid,amtw_amt_concept_id)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT 'AMT to MIMS linking table.';";
```

Comment: Probably not. In addition, the surrogate key (amtw_id) appears to be redundant. Your UNIQUE KEY could be PRIMARY

Comment: With the order of your `amtw_u1` keys, I believe the `amtw_propnameid_idx` would not be missed, since mysql could use the the `amtw_u1` as an index for `amtw_propnameid` alone. However, it could not use the `amtw_u1` index for queries on `amtw_amt_concept_id` alone. See the [MySQL doc on multicolumn indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)

Comment: Also, Strawberry is correct that you could use the composite key as a primary key, however reasonable people (and corporate standards) differ on whether you should have 'natural' primary keys so some would still use a synthetic PK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexes can only be used to optimize queries which use leftmost columns; as barry-johnson commented,

> If the table has a multiple-column index, any leftmost prefix of the
>   index can be used by the optimizer to find rows. For example, if you
>   have a three-column index on (col1, col2, col3), you have indexed
>   search capabilities on (col1), (col1, col2), and (col1, col2, col3).
>
> MySQL cannot use an index if the columns do not form a leftmost prefix
>   of the index. Suppose that you have the SELECT statements shown here:
>
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE col1=val1;
>
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE col1=val1 AND col2=val2;
>
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE col2=val2;
>
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE col2=val2 AND col3=val3;
>
> If an index exists on (col1, col2, col3),
>   only the first two queries use the index. The third and fourth queries
>   do involve indexed columns, but (col2) and (col2, col3) are not
>   leftmost prefixes of (col1, col2, col3).

[See the mysql documentation for more info](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)